# What would cause a defined variable to throw an undefined notice?

Tags: php, opencart

In opencart, I have a variable `sales_representative` in a foreach loop. It gets defined and put into an array, then gets out-put in a .tpl file. Everything works as it should. But I get a notice up top saying undefined index: `sales_representative`... If it was undefined I wouldn't be getting a result displayed... Any thoughts?

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: define it outside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure before you give it any value, initialize it first outside the loop by giving it a value of either 0 or ""

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you good sir.

Comment: Always a pleasure...done